Issue with uploading images and videos in next.js with nginx
I'm currently facing an issue with uploading images and videos in my Next.js application hosted on a VPS. Despite modifying the permissions for the necessary directories, I'm still unable to upload any media files. Here are the details of my setup:
nextjs 14, nginx, PM2 and VPS Ubuntu
I have set the permissions for the public directory:
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/nextjs/Project/public
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/nextjs/Project/public

nginx configuration:


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name (mydomain);

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /_next/static/ {
        alias /var/www/nextjs/Project/.next/static/;
    expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
       access_log off;
       log_not_found off;
       expires 365d;
       add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
    }


    location /recipe_img/ {
        alias /var/www/nextjs/Project/public/recipe_img/;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    
    location /tips_img/ {
        alias /var/www/nextjs/Project/public/tips_img/;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
  
    location /recipe_video/ {
        alias /var/www/nextjs/Project/public/recipe_video/;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location /tips_video/ {
        alias /var/www/nextjs/Project/public/tips_video/;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
}



And when I run:
pm2 logs

I got:

And when I run:
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

I got:

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on what else I might be missing or need to check? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
